# How to clear database entries on browser close in jsf?

Tags: spring, jsf-2, primefaces

In our application which makes
use of JSF/PrimeFaces, Spring and Hibernate once a user logs in, we set a flag in the DB until the user logs out from the application or the session expires. The problem is, we need to clear this flag in the DB even when he simply closes the browser without proper logout. To acheieve this, I have already tried jquery `$window.unload` and `$window.bind` functions which actually invokes some JS function which is associated with `<p:remoteCommand>` which in turn invokes a managed bean method to clear the DB. However, I later came to know this is not reliable and while testing also we saw the event was not firing consistently. How can I achieve the DB cleanup anyway?

Comment: would suggest a timeout based approach

Comment: There is no way to detect browser is closed. It is not possible.

Comment: Since the problem is sooo common I am forced to believe there must be some work around.Although Iamyet to try this,but can we write a filter and try to clear the flag in the destroy method of the filter?Just a hunch though!!!

Answer (score 1):

Listening on browser close is not reliable. You can use `beforeunload` event for that, but this is not supported on every webbrowser the world is aware of and even disableable/spoofable/hackable by the enduser. Then we're not talking about the race condition during firing the ajax request: would the ajax request arrive in its entirety right before the browser is closed? More than often this is not the case and the browser close wins over the ajax request.

Just listen server side on session expiration instead.

```
@WebListener
public class MyHttpSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        // NOOP.
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        HttpSession session = event.getSession();
        // Do your job here. 
        // ...
    }

}
```

Note that this is also invoked when you explicitly invoke `ExternalContext#invalidateSession()` (or `HttpSession#invalidate()`) during programmatic logout.

Comment: Hmm...I was also wondering something of that sort.Anyways thanx mate for your answer.Will try it out and let you know the result.

Comment: The problem is sessionDestroyed is not getting called when the browser is closed.Your thoughts on that?

Comment: It's called when session is destroyed, which happens X minutes after browser is closed. This X defaults to 30 minutes and is configurable in web.xml.

Comment: Ok..the parameter you are talking about is <session-timeout> right?In our case we are using it with value close to 10 hours.So in that case even if the sessionDestroyed method gets called that is useless isnt't it?Is my understanding correct?

Comment: 10 hours is just insane. Whatever problem you thought to solve with such an extremely large session timeout should be solved differently.